# Present view from UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, uitableview, swiftui, uikit, segue

I just created a UIKit tableView with `UIViewRepresentable`.

Now I need to present a new SwiftUI View, if a tableCell is selected.

This is what I've done so far:

```
struct UIKitTableView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var showDetail: Bool
```

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(showDetail: self.$showDetail)
}
```

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @Binding var showDetail: Bool

    /// Did select row at
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.showDetail = true
    }
```

Now in my SwiftUI view I can present the view with:

```
NavigationLink(destination: CellDetail(), isActive: self.$showDetail) {
```

But I also need to pass the data of the corrispective cell, and I was wondering which is the best approach.

My other question is: Is the @Binding showDetail approach correct? How can I improve my solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the situation, you're describing I don't understand why you would need to use `UIViewRepresentable`, since SwiftUI already have a very good implementation of it under the name of `List`

Here is a piece of code to help you show detail view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MasterView: View {
    private let cells = [
        "Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(cells, id: \.self) { cell in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(content: cell)) { // Creates all the logic to show detail view.
                    Text(cell)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("List")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    let content: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(content)
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `UIViewRepresentable` only helps when a view isn't implemented yet in SwiftUI.

Comment: I already know we have List. But since the trailing and leading action are not implementd in SwiftUI List, I choose for a UIViewRepresentable.

Comment: Then I would suggest you use the Introspect library